# Unable to save integer with NSUserDefaults

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

Basically I am trying to make it so when I restart the app the score for the user is saved, currently, the score reverts to zero upon closing and reopening the app. I have looked for numerous solutions on the internet but have found nothing. Here is my code (ViewController.m):

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int bytes;
int highScore;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    highScore = bytes;

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    // Snippet used to get your highscore from the prefs.
    highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)addBytes:(id)sender {
    highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
    highScore++;
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
    [_byteCounter setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore]];

}

@end
```

Comment: You're not saving the new value for `highScore`. Add `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];` to `addBytes:`.

Comment: Get rid of all of those needless calls to `synchronize`.

Comment: Also note that your `bytes` and `highScore` variables are not instance variables of your view controller. They are global variables to the file.

Answer (score 2):

you can use this code, i hope work it for you:

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setInteger:HighScore forKey:@"HighScore"];

Answer (score 0):

The user defaults is not being updated as you don't update it.

highscore++ only increments the your int variable, it doesn't increment the value in NSUserDefaults. So after you update highscore, you still need to update the NSUserDefaults by calling:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
```

Furthermore, you need not, and should not, call synchronize. The data will be flushed to the disk at some point later on automatically.

Comment: Make is simple. Use `integerForKey:` and `setInteger:forKey:`.

Answer (score 0):

Upon start up I was not displaying the saved value from NSUserDefaults to the label, here is my updated code that does save the integer upon restarting the app. (I'm very proud of my self!)

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

int bytes;
int highScore;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    highScore = bytes;

    highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
    [_byteCounter setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore]];

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}

- (IBAction)addBytes:(id)sender {
    highScore = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"HighScore"] intValue ];
    highScore++;
    [_byteCounter setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", highScore]];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:highScore] forKey:@"HighScore"];
}

@end
```

Comment: You have still not fixed the serious problem with your `bytes` and `highScore` global variables. They need to be instance variables, not global variables.

Comment: There is no reason for the line `highScore = bytes;` since you reassign a new value to `highScore` on the next line.

Comment: And use the provided `NSUserDefaults` API to save and read integer values. Use `integerForKey:` and `setInteger:forKey:`. And get rid of the obsolete call to `synchronize`.